# How to access name of files in dir

Tags: scala

How can I access the name of the file in below scala code :

```
object FileMatcher {

  private def filesHere = (new java.io.File("c:\\")).listFiles

  def filesEnding(query: String) = 
    for (file <- filesHere; if file.getName.endsWith(query))
      yield file.getName

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println(filesEnding(".js"))  
    }

}
```

I have one .js file and the output is : [Ljava.io.File;@df8f5e

I have tried changing 'yield file' to 'yield file.getName' but same result.

I'm assuming println(filesEnding(".js")) calls the toString method of whatever the def 'filesEnding' yields, is this correct ?

Comment: what is the _"same result"_? BTW, there's a `(` missing after the `if`...

Comment: @gilad hoch I think there is an implicit opening and close brackets for if statements in scala, they are optional. I've updated my question and the output is the same if I use brackets as part of if statement or not

Comment: try `if true 1 else 2` in the REPL. you'll get an error... so the `(` & `)` is a must. worked for me when i added it. BTW, did you meant `println(filesEnding(".js").mkString("\t","\n\t","\n"))`?

Comment: @gilad hoch yes that works but why does 'yield file.getName' not work ?

Comment: @gilad hoch ive tried with parenthesis around if statement but does'nt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filesEnding` yields an `Array[String]` (when you use `yield file.getName` and `Array[File]` when you use `yield file`) the `toString` method of Array, is the default `toString` implementation. which is the hash code printed... and this is exactly what you're getting. you probably meant `println(filesEnding(".js").mkString("\t","\n\t","\n"))` which should print your files nicely.

Comment: or alternately filesEnding(".js").foreach(println(_)) and do something with each result

Answer (score 1):

There's another method on File which reduces your work called list which lists names instead of Files. Depending on how you want to handle the condition where the searched for file is not found, you can either handle a thrown exception or directly receive the one file name you want with:

```
val jsFile = new File("C:\\").list.find(_ endsWith ".js").head
```

or generate an option and avoid the exception with:

```
val jsFileOpt = new File("C:\\").list.find(_ endsWith ".js").headOption
```

this however still fails with an exception if you pass a non directory path to the File constructor. To
protect against that wrap the potentially null list in an Option. With a directorie's content returned you get an Option[Array[String]] otherwise a None. Find will return Option[Option[String]] so use flatMap
to flatten this result back to Option[String].

```
val jsFileOpt = Option(new File("C:\\").list).flatMap(_.find(_ endsWith ".js"))
```

To process the result directly, ignoring errors, use the above extraction code with a map operation

```
Option(new File("C:\\").list).flatMap(_.find(_ endsWith ".js")) map {n =>
  // whatever you want to do with the file name.
}
```

Adapting your own code unchanged to just extract the first element in the returned Array

```
filesEnding(".js").head
```

Answer (score 0):

In one liner:

```
(new java.io.File("c:\\")).listFiles filter { _.getName.endsWith(query) } map { _.getName } foreach println
```

Naturally, replace `query` with whatever you want or put the line in a def with a argument named query.